# Cython with PyCharm 2021.2 professional doesn't recognize cdef (Green squiggly line)

Tags: python, pycharm, cython

Using PyCharm professional edition (2021.2).

pyx file compiles and runs, but PyCharm doesn't understand cython syntax.

'cdef' is with green squiggly line, when hovering : "typo: in word cdef'.
Same for cimport and others.

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in FILE-->SETTINGS-->EDITOR-->FILE TYPES:
Tab 'recognized File Types' --> Cython.
Added *.pyx.

That resolved issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).